# How can I fill the page when printing an MS word document with comments

Tags: ms-office, printing

I have a word document with comments. I wanna print it with the comments, but when I try, the document and the comments pane are shrunk, and do not fill the A4 paper properly (check photo). Tried changing the paper size from word, it went horribly. Is there any solution for this problem? No need for it to be in Word. 
If not, is there a way to present the comments inline, just pushed by a level (like in reply messages?) 
Thanks in advance!

[image: Photo]

Answer (score 0):

You get this result while printing with comments because Word tries to fit each original page to a single page while printing.

You can fill the paper better and get a more readable printout if you change the document's orientation from portrait to landscape before printing it out. This would cause both the appearance and pagination of the printed document to be different from the original but the paper would be better filled and the printout would be easier to read. You can change the document's orientation back to its original after printing it out.

You can change the document's orientation to Landscape either from Layout -> Orientation -> Landscape or File -> Page Setup (Page Attributes) -> Orientation. There is more information on this in this [MS Word support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-page-orientation-to-landscape-or-portrait-9b5ac1af-9998-4a37-962b-a82b689572a9?wt.mc_id=fsn_word_lay_out_pages#) if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

From the menu

File > Print

up pops a dialog box.  In the third field, which starts with 'Copies and Pages' change to 'Microsoft Word'.  Then you find another input field labelled 'Print What', select 'Document', *et voila*.

I'm running Word 16.66 on MacOS 12.3.1.